# How do I programmatically change the column referenced by Column Values Line in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to create a button in Spotfire that will change the Y-Axis in my chart to and from log- to linear-scale. I also have a line in the chart that is plotted from column values in a data table, and hence when the Y-Axis scale changes, I also need to change the line to a log scale.

Here is a picture of the property I want to change:

[image: Here is a picture of the property I want to change]

Here is a snippet of the code I have so far:

```
#import namespaces
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import AxisRange
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import FittingModels

#set variables
oil = oil_rate_time.As[VisualContent]()
islog = oil.YAxis.UseLogTransform

if islog:
    oil.YAxis.UseLogTransform = False
else:
    oil.YAxis.UseLogTransform = True

oil.ColumnValuesLine.YColumnReference
```

The last line is giving me the error that ColumnValuesLine is not an attribute in the ScatterPlot object.

Actual error text:
(Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in ExecuteForDebugging
File "", line 25, in 
AttributeError: 'ScatterPlot' object has no attribute 'ColumnValuesLine')

## Does anyone know why ColumnValuesLine isn't found despite being in the Spotfire API?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know the answer, this is how I did it:

```
#import namespaces
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

#set variables
oil = oil_rate_time.As[ScatterPlot]()
islog = oil.YAxis.TransformType
tctable = tc_Table

if islog == AxisTransformType.None:
    oil.YAxis.TransformType = AxisTransformType.Log10
    oil.FittingModels[0].YColumnReference = tctable.Columns[18]
else:
    oil.YAxis.TransformType = AxisTransformType.None
    oil.FittingModels[0].YColumnReference = tctable.Columns[9]
```